# Memory consumption in python comparision

Tags: python, memory

I have a doubt like why memory consumption in python is high when compared to other languages like C/C++ . size of int in python is 28 bytes in python 3+ whereas in C its just 4 bytes .

Python :

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof(1))
```

Output :
28 bytes

C:

```
  
// Driver code
int main()
{ 
    // Print the sizeof integer
    printf("Size of (int) = %lu"
           " bytes\n",
           sizeof(1));
  
    return 0;
}
```

Output :
Size of (int) = 4 bytes

Can sometime help me on understanding why python consumes higher bytes for the same datatype?

Comment: [cpython/Objects/longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/de6981680bcf6496e5996a853b2eaa700ed59b2c/Objects/longobject.c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the same data type. It's a related data type that happens to have the same name. For instance, C `int`s are only go up to 32767 (more in your case, but that's not guaranteed). Python `int`s are limited only by your memory, so I can do `2 ** 999999999`, for instance. This ability, along with a reference count and type information, is what takes up the extra space.

If you need smaller integers, particularly in arrays, consider using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/).